# Create new column based on conditions with different columns

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like advise on how to code a new column based on the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(AA = c("3454","345","5","345","567","79","43","2342","231","234","232","24"),
                 BB = c(123, 345, 7567, 234, 8679, 890, 812, 435345, 567, 568, 786, 678),
                 CC = c(1, 2, 6, 8, 22, 33, 56, 2, 34, 45, 45, 65), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

and I would like to create a new column called 'new' made out of the following conditions:

1. Group1 = AA > 300 & BB > 2000 & CC < 5
2. Group2 = AA ≥ 20 & BB ≤ 700 & CC > 60 but ≤ 70

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Group=ifelse(AA>300 & BB>2000 & CC<5,'Group1',
                       ifelse(AA>=20 & BB<=700 & (CC > 60 & CC<=70),'Group2',NA))) -> df1
```

Comment: ! thanks!! I had to make an edit because for group2 last condition needs to be >60 but ≤70. Could you ammend please? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Lili I have updated, Is that what you want?

Comment: this is great! Thanks!

Comment: @Lili Great! If you consider this answer was helpful you could accept it by clicking the tick in the left side of this answer :)

Comment: What happens when the number you try is negative? it gives me error (in a dataset that has negative values). AA> -300? or something like that

Comment: @Lili You should check the data, it actually will produce `NA` if conditions are not met. Of course the code you shared, you can try and see the results.

Answer (score 2):

`case_when()` in `dplyr` is designed to avoid the use of nested `ifelse()`s.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(new = case_when(
    AA > 300 & BB > 2000 & CC < 5 ~ "Group1",
    AA >= 20 & BB <= 700 & CC > 60 & CC <=70 ~ "Group2",
    TRUE ~ "other"
  ))
```